# Enqueue script/style with multiple GET parameters

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to enqueue a style with two GET parameters, but the output is not correct. Here's what I have:

```
wp_enqueue_style('colors-css', '/root/assets/css/colors.css?style=blue');
```

The problem is, when it's rendered to the browser, it looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/root/assets/css/colors.css?style=blue&#038;ver=3.9
```

It seems when there is already one parameter defined in the URL, Wordpress does not know how to add the version correctly with the `&` symbol. Any ideas how to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

`esc_url` is run on the stylesheet URL and that [converts those characters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2891). You can work around it with a couple of filters.

```
function style_params($src, $handle) {
  if ('twentyfourteen-style' == $handle) {
    add_filter('clean_url','alter_clean_url',10,3);
  }
  return $src;
}
add_filter('style_loader_src','style_params',10,2);

function alter_clean_url($good_protocol_url, $original_url, $_context ) {
  remove_filter('clean_url','alter_clean_url',10,3);
  $good_protocol_url = html_entity_decode($good_protocol_url);
  $good_protocol_url = $good_protocol_url.'&abc=def';
  return $good_protocol_url;
}
```